# Angular shows empty screen after updating ng-if variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using an integer to represent a state in my application, in which I have several(3) containers using `<div ng-if="state == value">` to display the proper information for that page. The issue is that when `state` changes, the screen turns white. No errors, no nothing. It's just blank.

```js
angular.module('CharCount')

  .controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $timeout) {

    $scope.state = 0;
    
    $scope.stateText = "waiting";
    
    $scope.clicked = function() {
      $timeout(function() {
        $scope.state = 1;
        $scope.state = "loading";
        $scope.test(null, function() {
          $scope.state = 2;
          $scope.state = "finished, should show State C";
        });
      });
    };
    
    $scope.test = function(a, callback) {
      $timeout(callback);
    };
    

  });
```

```html
<html>

  <head>
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="CharCount">
    <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
      <div ng-if="state == 0">
        State A<br>
        {{stateText}}<br>
        <button ng-click="clicked()">click me</button>
      </div>
      
      <div ng-if="state == 1">
        State B<br>
        {{stateText}}
      </div>
      
      <div ng-if="state == 2">
        State C<br>
        {{stateText}}
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="angular-character-count.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

If anyone can explain why this happens, It'd help a lot.

Answer (score 1):

There are many problems in the code:

1. To get the app instance use the getter, pass the second parameter to the `module()` as empty array. ==> `angular.module('CharCount', [])`
2. Inside `$timeout` callback, the variable `state` is assigned a string.

   ```
   $scope.state = 1;
   $scope.state = "loading"; // This is incorrect
   ```

   As there is no condition in the view and all other conditions are evaluated to false, no element will be shown.
3. Logical Error: The values should be set before calling the `$timeout`.

   ```
   $scope.state = 1;
   $scope.stateText = "loading";
   ```

   Move these statements above `$timeout`.

**Demo:**

```js
angular.module('CharCount', [])                      // <--- #1

.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $timeout) {

  $scope.state = 0;
  $scope.stateText = "waiting";

  $scope.clicked = function() {
    $scope.state = 1;                                // <--- #3
    $scope.stateText = "loading";                    // <--- #2

    $timeout(function() {
      $scope.test(null, function() {
        $scope.state = 2;
        $scope.stateText = "finished, should show State C"; // <--- #2
      });
    }, 1000);
  };

  $scope.test = function(a, callback) {
    $timeout(callback);
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="CharCount">
  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div ng-if="state == 0">
      State A
      <br>{{stateText}}
      <br>
      <button ng-click="clicked()">click me</button>
    </div>

    <div ng-if="state == 1">
      State B
      <br>{{stateText}}
    </div>

    <div ng-if="state == 2">
      State C
      <br>{{stateText}}
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```